# Using ngrok with Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, base-url

I have a virtual host set up. My local url is `http://test.local`

When I start [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), my local url will become: 
`http://test.local.ngrok.io` so I changed my base secure and unsecure url to: `http://test.local.ngrok.io/`

My problem is that I cannot login anymore in admin side . I am getting this error validation error: `Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.`, after I cleared my cache and session folder and deleted the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` & `web/cookie/cookie_path` from core_config_data.

Interesting part is if changed back my base url in `http://test.local/` I can login instantly.

Any ideas what should I try more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a virtual host issue, I added one also for the ngrok domain and it worked

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin myemail@myemail.com
   ServerName test.local.ngrok.io
   ServerAlias www.test.local.ngrok.io
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
         AllowOverride All
         Allow from All
         Require all granted  
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```